# How can I start my project from .next folder?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to start my NextJS project from build folder (.next). I ran `next build` command, got .next folder and... I tried start project from .next folder many times and used a lot of ways, but I wasn't successful. Can anyone explain me what I need to do for starting my NextJS project from build folder?

Comment: next build && next start

https://nextjs.org/docs

Comment: It doesn't work if I do it from .next directory because I get error that next not found.

Comment: It's not meant to be executed from the .next directory, run it from the project root

Comment: But I need deploy this project. For this purpose I need start my project from any folder separate from project root directory.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please mention your `package.json` file inside `scripts: {}` what was there ?
According to NextJS docs If you run like

If npm then :  `npm run build`

If yarn : `yarn build`

You will get `.next` folder with build files. then you should run `npm run start` or `yarn start` which will running the project from `.next`

If you want Static HTML export which slightly different.
Step 1 : open package.json and update this `"build": "next build && next export"` inside `scripts:{}` and save.
Step 2: Run the build command `yarn build or npm run build` it will give you `out` folder with static files which you can deploy or run anywhere in your server. Official [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export)  and also `npx serve out` for node server.

Comment: I know about everything you mentioned. But I got .next folder and further I want to move it to e.g. desktop and run from desktop (if .next is analog build folder it must work), but it doesn't work. How can I deploy my .next (not Vercel, but my nginx web-server)?

Comment: this did not answer the question. you want to move dir to desktop as you said it and run in there for example. i did not came across any answer that resolves this. question